# How can i add a spinner to UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm calling UIImagePickerController in my app for uploading photo to the WebServer. I want to know how can i add a spinner to UIImagePickerController like below?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a custom overlay view to the screen, with  `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `UITextView` subviews.